Find the file extension from file name passed into powershell as a string argument
I am an absolute beginner with PowerShell,
With a pair of PS1 files.
The first one does a couple of basic checks, and will then Launch a file whose full path  has been passed in as a string. $args[0]
Got that all working OK,
But the filename being passed in could be either a batch file or a PS1.
I have two problems:
How can I , within the script get the file extension from the name?
Would it be easier/better to pass the extension as another argument?
And then run the batch or the PS1 as appropriate.
If the extension is PS1 then run the PS1,
If BAT, then run the batch file
Thanks

"If the extension is PS1 then run the PS1, If BAT, then run the batch file" - PowerShell already does this automatically. What exact problem are you trying to solve here?

As I said I'm a beginner. On this one, having found the extension, Which I was surprised to find is that  GetExtension seems to od the job.. So now I just need to run the file that was in Args[0] Now, if Powershell does that automatically, I may not need to know the extension , so all I need to do is to run the file: Would it be  the same command , like Call $FileToRun?

As I said: you don't need to know the extension. Just invoke with the call operator: & $Args[0]

You can you use the following to get the extension:
(Get-ChildItem .\test.ps1).Extension

The output is ".ps1" in this case.
You would need to use something like this in your script:
switch ((Get-ChildItem $argv[0]).Extension) {
    ".ps1" {
        # Do this for ps1
    }
    ".bat" {
        # Do this for bat
    }
    default {
        # Do this for something else
    }


as he's going to do "stuff" later to the passed file, I suggest $File=Get-ChildItem $args[0] and then switch($File.extension) so he can use $File later as necessary without touching $args[0].

Here is the code so far
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$FiltoRun = $args[0]
Get the file extension
$extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($FiltoRun)
The file extension will either be .BAT, or .PSI
So I just need the code to run it.
If Powershell just knows what to do, then I just need to run $FilToRun.
The only reason for needing the extension was if the calling process was different between the two

@dmhzx, code in comments is basically unreadable. Please edit the question and include the source code as text. Select the code text and use the {} icon. No pictures.
